# ReactJS AJAX best practice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I am currently trying to learn ReactJS and can't really find any consistent documentation (even the official docs look a bit messed up), especially around AJAX, it all seems a bit cobbled together. I've ended up using the JQuery $.get method which seems like a bit of a cheat.

I have the code below but just wondered if there was a cleaner way of dealing with simple AJAX calls? I'm also firing this off within componentDidMount which seemed the most logical, looking at the lifecycle.

Any help is welcomed!!

```
getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        numberOfItems: 0,
        items: []
    };
},

componentDidMount: function () {

    $('#MyContainer .loading').show();

    $.get(this.props.source, function (result) {
            var response = result.response;
            this.setState({
                numberOfItems: response.list.numberOfItems,
                items: response.list
            });
        }.bind(this))
        .done(function () {
            $('#MyContainer.loading').hide();
        });
},

render: function() {
    return(
        //Stuff here
    )
};


ReactDOM.render(
    <RecommendationsList source="/my/api/call/here"/>,
    document.getElementById('MyContainer')
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React is just the view layer. It doesn't concern itself much with fetching data and leaves that up to you. I use `jQuery`'s AJAX functionality for ease of use but you can really use whatever [**AJAX library**](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=xhr) you want.

From the code you have provided, you are doing everything correct. You are waiting for the component to mount `componentDidMount`.

One note to say about keeping asynchronous JavaScript clean, with multiple callbacks; I would assign the call to a variable.

```
var request = $.get(this.props.source, function (result) {
    var response = result.response;
    this.setState({
        numberOfItems: response.list.numberOfItems,
        items: response.list
    });
}.bind(this));
```

Then bind listeners to that variable.

```
request.done(function () {
    $('#MyContainer.loading').hide();
});
```

Comment: Great thanks, like all evolving frameworks the docs are so muddy

Answer (score 1):

#### Using react state

If you are using normal react states to han0dle your data (I would suggest not to), then your approach is fine. KISS (Keep it simple and stupid).

```
Make AJAX call --> In success callback, update state
```

#### Using Redux

You are looking for [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) module. It allows you to dispatch actions in a async way.

Redux actions are supposed to be synchronous. But we can achieve async actions using a powerful redux feature called `middlewares`. So the idea is to create an action creator that returns an actions and dispatches on promise.

Read more on the [middlewares](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html) in redux documentation.

Comment: It doesn't look like they are using Redux though.

Comment: Thanks I will look into this - seems next level to me